# What file-based database options exist besides SQLite and SQL Server Compact Framework?

Tags: database, sqlite, nhibernate, orm, sql-server-ce

I am creating a WPF application (very little WPF, basically just an embedded browser in a window) that will pull data from a file based database. I've been looking in to SQLite and SQL Server CE. Does anyone know of any other options worth researching?

The database needs to be encrypted and work with nHibernate or some other ORM.

Please let me know what file-based databases and ORMs you've had experience with and what that experience was like.

Any reasons to use SQLite over SQL Server CE or vice versa?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Those two are your best bet. A JET-Driver (Access) can be obtained form this contrib project: https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.JetDriver